# "Could not parse configuration file..." when I add EF6 to a solution

Tags: entity-framework

I get an error when I add EF6 to a solution. I think it also happens when I update the model from the database. The error shows up in the Output window right after I add EF: "Could not parse the configuration file. The error message is: 'Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))' Try editing the file manually and then saving it."

The "error" doesn't seem to have any influence on the compiling or running of the application (or the function of EF). However, an error like this is always disturbing when it's with the technology that is supposed to be the linchpin of your data management strategy.

Comment: +1 I have started to see that exact same message in our VS2013 solution the past few days. Not sure yet what causes it. Also, it does not have any influence (yet) at compile, debug or runtime.

Comment: I have better repro'd the error.

Open the solution with VS

Open the *.edmx in the designer (double click on file from solution explorer)

Click on the white space anywhere on the designer's surface

The error appears in the Output.


If I clear the Output, I can compile, run, close *.edmx, re-open *.edmx, all without error. It seems this occurs only when I open VS, then the *.edmx, then click on the designer surface the first time.

If I never open the *.edmx in the designer of VS, I never see the error in the Output window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that I have discovered the problem. I can repro it on my development machine and a couple of other dev machines.

I am using VS 2013. The solution that I was using included a second project, a setup/deployment project, InstallShield Limited Edition Project. If I remove that project, the errors go away.

If I create a new project, add EF via Nuget, add an EF model to the solution and then add this setup project I can repro the error. If you try it yourself, just remember you need to open VS and the solution, open the model in the designer, click anywhere in the whitespace of the design surface, the error should pop up in the Output. The details are up there in an earlier post.

Comment: That sounds very right to me. We also added an InstallShield LE to our solution about 2 weeks ago. I haven't had the chance yet to verify in our setup, but it sounds very much like you've narrowed this error down to the right spot. Good work!

Comment: Yep, here also in combination with InstallShield LE. But on Visual Studio 2015

Comment: yep, seeing it in VS 2015 with IS LE as well

Comment: VS 2015 Update 2 with IS LE here too. I unload the Install Shield project before opening the Entity Designer - good workaround.