# EDMX in VS 2013 hangs in any click

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, edmx

I don't know what had happened in VS 2013 but any click in EDMX editor hangs the system for more than 1 minute. Even the page close hangs VS for a long time. Right mouse click hangs the system for 1 hour in a 400 tables EDMX file.

What can be going on? Surely exists a module being called in VS 2013 during EDMX editor processing. Any clue on where to search can be helpful.

I'm using EFTools 6.1.3 and VS 2013 Update 5.

Thanks,
Marco Castro

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few month went by and there's still no answer on this one so I share my experience here (VS 2015 Update 2):

In the Visual Sudio Output-Window (Show output from: Entity Data Model) I found the following error message:
Could not parse the configuration file. The error message is: 'Bibliothek nicht registriert. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))'. Try editing the file manually and then saving it.

After googling this error I found the following StackOverflow entry: ["Could not parse configuration file..." when I add EF6 to a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207518/could-not-parse-configuration-file-when-i-add-ef6-to-a-solution)

I also do have an Install Shield project in my solution. So if I unload this Install Shield project the error is gone and I am able to use the Entity Designer.